# Project row details as columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables for the library schema

```
Table Book(BookID(Primary Key & Identity), Name, Author, Available)
Table BookDetails(BookDetailsID(Primary key & Identity), BookID(Foreign key for BookID),AttributeID(Foreign Key for Attribute),AttributeValue)
Table BookAttributes(AttributeID,Name)
```

So, the Book table just contains basic details and BookDetails table contains more finer details like ISBN, Publication, Pages etc..

I want a report of all the books with their attributes, I am able to get the Attributedetails of the book but not sure how to project them as columns in my result set. i am looking for something like following

```
BookID     BookName      ISBN  Publication  .....
-----------------------------------------------------
10         HarryPotter1  xxxx  xxxxxx 
20         HarryPotter2  xxxx  xxxxxx
30         HarryPotter3  xxxx  xxxxxx
40         HarryPotter4  xxxx  xxxxxx
```

where ISBN and Publication etc are coming from BookDetails table where they are stored as separate rows for wach ISBN and Publication attributes keyed by Book ID. How do I project the Attribute values which are rows in BookDetails table into columns in my result set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need a PIVOT to do this, and dynamic SQL (this figures out what the columns are supposed to be, then creates the SQL based on that, then executes that SQL).  I think this will work:

```
DECLARE
    @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SQL_Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = ISNULL( @Columns + ', ', '') + '[' + b.[Name] + ']' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM BookAttributes) AS b

SELECT @SQL_Statement = '
WITH cte_Flat AS
(
SELECT
    b.BookID,
    bd.AttributeValue
    ba.[Name]
FROM 
    Book AS b
JOIN
    BookDetails AS bd
ON  
    b.BookID = bd.BookID
JOIN
    BookAttributes AS ba
ON
    bd.AttributeID = ba.AttributeID
)
SELECT
    BookID,
    ' + @Columns + '
FROM
    cte_Flat
PIVOT
    (
      MAX(AttributeValue)
      for [Name] in (' + @Columns + ')
    ) AS u'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @SQL_Statement = @SQL_Statement
```

Comment: agreed, but this just gives the book attributes as rows, meaning for each book  you have a row for publication, ISBN etc... i am looking for Book Attributes names as column , like my example in question, where publication , ISBN are actual columns but not rows

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need a PIVOT to do this, and dynamic SQL (this figures out what the columns are supposed to be, then creates the SQL based on that, then executes that SQL).  I think this will work:

```
DECLARE
    @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SQL_Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = ISNULL( @Columns + ', ', '') + '[' + b.[Name] + ']' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM BookAttributes) AS b

SELECT @SQL_Statement = '
WITH cte_Flat AS
(
    SELECT
        b.BookID,
        bd.AttributeValue
        ba.[Name]
    FROM Book AS b
        JOIN BookDetails AS bd ON b.BookID = bd.BookID
        JOIN BookAttributes AS ba ON bd.AttributeID = ba.AttributeID
)
SELECT
    BookID,
    ' + @Columns + '
FROM
    cte_Flat
PIVOT
    (
      MAX(AttributeValue)
      for [Name] in (' + @Columns + ')
    ) AS u'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @SQL_Statement = @SQL_Statement
```

Comment: This is as good as the other answer as well, but like I said, I want the Book row with the Attribute Names as columns and their values as column values for that book row..like I mentioned in my example in question